# Equivalence to essentially self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In a book I have found a statement (without proof):

> Let $A$ be a symmetric operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is essentially self-adjoint
> 2. $\nu(i)=\nu(-i)=0$
> 3. The ranges of $A-i \mathbb{1}$ and $A+i\mathbb 1$ are dense in $\mathcal H$

Here $\nu(\lambda)$ is defined as the dimension of the $\ker(A^*-\lambda \mathbb 1)$.

I don't really know where to begin with the proof. For 2. and 3. is it necessary to have both parts of the statement or are they already equivalent to each other?

How can the statement be proven? I think at this point I would appreciate hints more than the direct proof.

Comment: **Note:** (for readers) Symmetric = self-adjoint over its domain (generally a proper subset, in some literature the subset must be dense).  Essentially self-adjoint = symmetric, but with a self-adjoint extension.

Comment: With a cursory glance, it seems like it's easy to prove $1 \implies 2$ and $1 \implies 3$.  From there, it suffices to prove one of the converses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq H \rightarrow H$ is a densely-defined symmetric linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$, then the following holds in $H\times H$:
$$
           \mathcal{G}(A^*)=\overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}\oplus\mathcal{N}(A^*-iI)\oplus\mathcal{N}(A^*+iI),
$$
where $\mathcal{G}(A^*)$ is the graph of $A^*$ and $\overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}$ is the closure of the graph of $A$ in $H\times H$. (I'm being sloppy about the notation of $\mathcal{N}(A^*\pm iI)$ because it's really the graph of the restriction of $A^*$ to these subspaces.)

Comment: This is an elegant and illuminating formula, but proving the non-trivial part "$\subseteq$" of your formula is probably at about the same difficulty level as the non-trivial part (3)$\implies$(1) of the OP's formulation.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Actually, it's not so bad. $(y,A^*y) \perp \mathcal{G}(A)$ iff $(x,y)+(Ax,A^*y)=0$ for all $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$, which holds iff $A^*y\in\mathcal{D}(A^*)$ and $(A^*)^2y+y=0$. The set of such $y$ easily decomposes in $\mathcal{N}(A^*+iI)\oplus\mathcal{N}(A^*-iI)$.